# Expression Blend does not allow to select Solution Configuration/Platform

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Our solution is built using Release|x86; however, when our designers try to build using Blend they are forced to use Any CPU which we don't want to to add since it's going to change the behavior. I checked version 4, and it does not seem to address this issue.

Is there a way to specify Solution Configuration/Platform when using Blend? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you edited your .csproj files by hand instead of using the GUI.  Unlike Visual Studio, Blend reads the platform and configuration from each project file rather than from the solution file.  Your project files probably start out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
```

That's the default configuration for a project and is what Blend is reading.  Change each .csproj to specify Release and x86 as the default config and Blend should respect it.

From what I can see, there is no way to specify a given configuration in Blend -- it always chooses the default.